# How to join two tables and replace null in second table with zero

Tags: sql

[image]

When I try to join table A with B, I get only two rows - I do not get data for '55A' in ProdID column as it is missing in table B. How do I ensure that I get three rows with zero for price for missing ProdID

```
Query used:
select A.orderNo, B.Price
from A,B
where A.ProdID=B.ProdIDl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should follow a simple rule:  never use commas in the `join` clause.  Explicit `join` syntax is much more powerful.  And, it has been around for a long, long time.

The `join` you want is a `left join`.  It keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether or not there are matches in the second table.  The columns in the second table are given `NULL` values when there is no match.  To convert the `NULL` to a `0`, you can use the ANSI standard function `coalesce()`:

```
select A.orderNo, coalesce(B.Price, 0) as Price
from A left join
     B
     on A.ProdID = B.ProdID;
```

Answer (score 1):

just use [LEFT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)/[RIGHT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) JOIN

after that you can use the [COALESCE function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) like this `COALESCE(B.Price,0) Price`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
     LEFT JOIN B
              ON A.ProdID=B.ProdID
```

If the elements of table A have no match in talble B, this query will display them but setting  a `NULL` on the right side as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can join these tables(*tableA*,*tableB*):

```
SELECT A.orderNo, B.Price
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
ON A.ProdID = B.ProdID
WHERE 1
```